# Does not work cursor function in python

Tags: python, mysql, while-loop, cursor

i have python script to get domains from sql to nginx.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import MySQLdb

query = 'SELECT name_of_domain FROM domain_table'
database_connect = MySQLdb.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=password, db=database, port=port)
cursor = database_connect.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
while True:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print (row)
```

In this case everything is ok. In a loop, i have received line by line all rows. 
I decided to use function:
My function:

```
def get_cursor():
    database_connect = MySQLdb.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=password, port=port, db=database, charset='utf8')
    database_connect.autocommit(True)
    return database_connect.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

And i have tried to use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import MySQLdb

cursor = get_cursor()
query = 'SELECT name_of_domain FROM domain_table'
cursor.execute(query)
while True:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print (row)
```

But in this case, i have received only one result, and my next functions don't work. Where i have error ? Please help.

Comment: did you try: row = cursor.fetchmany( size=1 ) ?

Comment: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'str'`

Comment: what happens if you put `MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor` into the one that works? Does that produce the same behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but *think* that this is because the `cursor.execute()` returns an iterator, which is used up by the first `.fetchone()` call.

see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html

try replacing

```
while True:
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print (row)
```

with

```
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
```

Comment: sorry. it did not help